# Projeto no Qt compila no Ubuntu mas não compila no Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ubuntu, qt

Tenho um projeto para a faculdade originalmente produzido na plataforma linux usando o Qt Creator e preciso migrá-lo para o windows. 
Tentei compilar mas o projeto apresenta erros em um único header file e não entendo o por quê .

Segue anexo de parte dos erros :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a classe :

```
#ifndef PROPERTIES_H
#define PROPERTIES_H

#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Properties
{
public:
    enum DataType
    {
        INT,
        VOID,
        FLOAT,
        BOOLEAN,
        STRING
    };

    struct Property
    {
        Property(const std::string& name_, Properties::DataType type_) :
            name(name_), type(type_) {}

        const std::string name;
        const Properties::DataType type;
    };

    Properties(){}
    Properties(const Properties& prop)
    {
        *this = prop;
    }
    ~Properties()
    {
        for(DataMap::iterator it = dataMap.begin(); it != dataMap.end(); ++it)
        {
            delete it->second;
        }
    }
    Properties& operator=(const Properties& prop)
    {
        for(DataMap::const_iterator it = prop.dataMap.begin(); it != prop.dataMap.end(); ++it)
            dataMap.insert(make_pair(it->first, it->second->getCopy()));

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Properties& set(const std::string& name, const T& value)
    {
        DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.find(name);
        if(it != dataMap.end())
        {
            BaseDataRec *rec = it->second;
            if(rec->type == getType<T>())
                ((DataRec<T>*)rec)->data = value;
        }
        else
            dataMap.insert(make_pair(name, new DataRec<T>(value, getType<T>())));

        return *this;
    }

    bool has(const std::string& name) const
    {
        DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.find(name);
        if(it != dataMap.end())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool has(const std::string& name) const
    {
        DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.find(name);
        if(it != dataMap.end())
        {
            if(it->second->type == getType<T>())
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get(const std::string& name) const
    {
        DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.find(name);
        if(it != dataMap.end())
        {
            BaseDataRec *rec = it->second;
            if(rec->type == getType<T>())
                return ((DataRec<T>*)rec)->data;
            else
                std::cout << "\"" << name << "\" não é do tipo solicitado." << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "\"" << name << "\" não encontrado." << std::endl;

        throw std::runtime_error("Erro ao obter o parametro.");
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get(const std::string& name, const T& def) const
    {
        DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.find(name);
        if(it != dataMap.end())
        {
            BaseDataRec *rec = it->second;
            if(rec->type == getType<T>())
                return ((DataRec<T>*)rec)->data;
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\"" << name << "\" não é do tipo solicitado." << std::endl;
                throw std::runtime_error("Erro ao obter o parametro.");
            }
        }

        return def;
    }

    std::list<Property> getSummary()
    {
        std::list<Property> result;
        for(DataMap::const_iterator it = dataMap.begin(); it != dataMap.end(); ++it)
            result.push_back(Property(it->first, it->second->type));
        return result;
    }

private:
    struct BaseDataRec
    {
        BaseDataRec(DataType t) :
            type(t)
        {}

        virtual BaseDataRec* getCopy() = 0;

        DataType type;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct DataRec: public BaseDataRec
    {
        DataRec(const T& d, DataType t) :
            BaseDataRec(t), data(d)
        {}

        virtual DataRec<T>* getCopy()
        { return new DataRec<T>(data, type); }

        T data;
    };

    template<typename T>
    DataType getType() const
    {
        std::cout << "Não há suporte ao tipo solicitado." << std::endl; return VOID;
    }

    typedef std::map<std::string, BaseDataRec*> DataMap;
    DataMap dataMap;
};


#define SUPPORT_TYPE(type, enumtype) \
    template<> \
    inline Properties::DataType Properties::getType<type>() const \
    { return enumtype; }


SUPPORT_TYPE(int, Properties::INT)
SUPPORT_TYPE(float, Properties::FLOAT)
SUPPORT_TYPE(bool, Properties::BOOLEAN)
SUPPORT_TYPE(std::string, Properties::STRING)



#endif // PROPERTIES_H
```

Comment: Vc já testou alterando os nomes dos valores da enumeração `DataType`? Não tenho certeza absoluta, mas talvez no Windows já exista alguma definição de `INT` totalmente em maiúsculo...